# the purpose of using a bool in swift & program crush

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm watching the Stanford iOS8 class online, and I have a question about the purpose of using a bool.

The first section is about creating a calculator. The first lesson of this section is about displaying the numbers, which are pressed by the user, on the screen of the calculator. The instructor pointed out that in order to display the numbers without the zero attached to the beginning of each number, the program should have this boolean variable.

```
var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber: Bool = false
```

However, I don't really understand how does it work in this program or why did the instructor use it this way. Can someone explain it for me please? And why does my program crush after pressing any two numbers on the keypad? Thanks in advance!

I would've added pictures, but I cannot because I don't have enough reputation points.

The display screen before using the boolean variable would be like this: 
0567

The display screen after using the boolean variable would be like this:
567

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!


    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber: Bool = false


    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {

        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber {

           display.text = display.text! + digit

        } else {

            display.text = digit

            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber = true

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not addressing the case of zero `0` in your code. That is what the boolean is for. If `userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping` is `true`, it means you are *not* at the beginning of the input.

Think it through in pseudo-code:

```
if userIsTypingFirstDigit (that is, userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping == false)  
   if digitIsZero
      add the zero to the input text
      (but leave userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping as false) 
   else 
      replace the input text with the digit (which replaces any zeros typed)
      set userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping to true
else
   add the digit to the input text (including zeros)
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

1) About

```
var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber: Bool = false
```

Here the `userIsInTheMiddleOfTypyingANmuber` ( a `flag` variable ) is to make sure reset the `display` Label every time when you start to input a number.

For example, to calculate `12345 + 789`.

> 1)  Input `1`.        ----> Initially, `flag` is **false**, so `display` = `1`
>
> 2)  Continue input `2345` ---->`flag` is **true** now, then `display` =
>   `12345`
>
> 3)  input `+`  ----> Reset `flag` to **false**
>
> 4)  input `7` ----> Since `flag` is **false**, then `display` =
>   `7`(That's make `12345` gone, reset).
>                  Otherwise, the `display` would be `123457`(WRONG!!!).
>
> 5) Continue input `89` ----> `flag` is **true** now, then `display` = `789`

2) About crash,
Because there is no related error message info, it's hard to tell.
But, basically, to make sure all `Label` `Button` controllers are connected well to ViewController, or it would cause crash.